# How to insert in Scrollbar window values in grid mode?

Tags: tkinter

I want to display my data from a mysql table into a scrollbar window in tkinker.
This is what I get:

[image]

The function that creates and insert in scrollbar is:

```
def list():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    data = Tk()
    data.geometry("250x100")
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(data)
    scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    mylist = Listbox(data, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    cursor = car_dealer.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `employee`")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in range(len(result)):
        mylist.insert(END, str(result[i][0]) + ' ' + str(result[i][1]) + ' ' + str(result[i][2]) + ' ' + str(result[i][3]))
    mylist.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command = mylist.yview)
    
    data.mainloop()
    car_dealer.close()
```

What I want is to have values on columns(4 columns).

What can I do ?

Comment: Try using [`ttk.Treeview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview) instead of `Listbox`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you ! How to apply style on specific window ? I used ```style = ttk.Style() style.theme_use('clam')``` and it worked for main window but for a window that opens when select an option from a menu it doesn't apply...

Comment: update: I passed the window as argument of Style, for those who need to know :))